# Why does adding spaces around bash comparison operator change the result?

Tags: bash

Could someone explain why spaces around `==` change the comparison result? The following:

```
if [[ 1 == 2 ]] ; then echo ok ; fi
```

prints nothing, while

```
if [[ 1==2 ]] ; then echo ok ; fi
```

prints `ok`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"1==2" is a single 4-character string, not an expression involving the `==` operator. Non-empty strings always evaluate to true in the context of the conditional expression `[[ ... ]]`. Whitespace is mandatory around the `==` operator.

Like everything else in `bash`, the contents of `[[ ... ]]` are simply a white-space-separated list of arguments. The `bash` grammar doesn't know how to parse conditional expressions, but it does know how to interpret a list of 3 arguments like `1`, `==`, and `2` in the context of the `[[ ... ]]` compound command.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's just a string, consider testing :

```
[[ foobar ]]
```

it will be `true`.

This is useful to test if a variable is set or not like in this example :

```
x='foobar'
[[ $x ]] # true
```

and now

```
x=''
[[ $x ]] # false
```

### Finally

The **spaces are mandatory** in a test expression