# Shell script accepting anything as a parameter

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, if-statement

This is odd.

Here's my file

```
#!/bin/bash
num=$#
clear
ip=$1
op=$2
ts=$3
echo $ts
if [ $ts=='32' ]; then
        echo "32 Bit"
elif [ $ts=='64' ]; then
        echo "64 Bit"
else
        echo "NONE"
fi
echo "Complete!"
```

Now, there's more to the file, but the if statement, no matter what, will say "32 bit" even when I run ./compile.sh input output 64.

I've also tried surrounding quotes around the variables. The first echo statement actually outputs "64".

Comment: fix `if [ $ts=='32' ]; then`  into `if [ $ts =='32' ]; then`  there is a space at both side of `==`

Answer (score 3):

Use single `=` to test strings.

```
if [ $ts = "32" ]
```

So your script becomes this now:

```
#!/bin/bash
num=$#
clear
ip=$1
op=$2
ts=$3
echo $ts
if [ $ts = "32" ]; then
        echo "32 Bit"
elif [ $ts = "64" ]; then
        echo "64 Bit"
else
        echo "NONE"
fi
echo "Complete!"
```

**EDIT:**
As Chris mentioned even with double `=` it will work but you have to have spaces around that `==` like below

```
if [ $ts == "32" ]
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much. How embarrassing.

Comment: `=` instead of `==` is not the issue. It is rather about the spaces around the operator. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365307/why-does-adding-spaces-around-bash-comparison-operator-change-the-result

Comment: I will! The minimum threshold of time has not yet been met, but in 8 minutes I'll be sure to accept it.

Comment: `==` only works in `bash`; the POSIX standard does not support it. If `==` works in `[`, then `[[` is also available and should probably be used instead (in which case, you can safely use `==`).

Answer (score 1):

Recommend to use case statement, simple and clean

```
#!/bin/bash
num=$#
clear
ip=$1
op=$2
ts=$3
echo $ts

case $ts in 
  "32") echo "32 Bit" ;;
  "64") echo "64 Bit" ;;
  *)    echo "NONE" ;;
esac
echo "Complete!"
```