# Why does this string comparison if statement fail to work

Tags: bash, sh

I expect the following code to print only one `x`, but it always gives two:

```
#!/bin/sh
read i
if [[ $i!=1 ]];then
    echo x
fi
if [[ $i==1 ]];then
    echo x
fi
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15365307/2002514

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your script is invalid in POSIX `sh`, since **`[[` is undefined in `sh`**.

In `bash`, on the other hand, **you're missing spaces around comparison operators** `!=` and `==`. That's why the expression inside `[[ ]]` is treated as a non-zero length string, which is truthy. Hence, `echo` is printed twice.

As suggested so many times on StackOverflow, it's always good to run your shell scripts through [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) (available as command line tool also), which will help you catch and explain many of such errors.